# How does wordpress display plugins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I can sort of see the logic in displaying plugin information via a shortcode. I'd assume by putting the shortcode on a post, it will add a echo do_shortcode into the post file.

What I don't understand is when there is no shortcode, such as a rating plugin that I am using.

The plugin has a folder in my website where the information is stored. This information is displayed on my front page (post rating) but there is no code in my index.php that calls for any of the plugin files.

Where does wordpress call for the plugin files to be loaded and how can I see which file is being loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of plugins use hooks in order to implement their functionality. You can find a list of these hooks on the WordPress developer site [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

One of the most commonly used examples is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which is used to implement front-end styling and javascript files.

Take a look the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), specifically [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109869/how-do-filters-and-hooks-really-work-in-php), for more information on how filters and hooks are powered.